# Login Via Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am developing an Android app in which user will have choice that he/she can Login in main app using a Facebook account (FB Login). I came to this tutorial in this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/).

While developing the app, I came to an error in a `.java` file that:

> the Facebook class is not available. Create Facebook class.

I am not getting anything as I have already included Facebook Android SDK in my project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First check Library in your project's properties-> android. In library Add facebook(com_facebook_android) library.

Comment: I did everything written on tutorial...I did add library also

Comment: Actually it is showing an error at the beginning of .java file that create Facebook class.